# Updating a follower cluster configuration - limiting tables

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I am trying to update a **follower cluster configuration** with a limited set of tables. According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/kusto/attached-database-configuration?view=azure-cli-latest#az-kusto-attached-database-configuration-update), I use the PowerShell command

```
az kusto attached-database-configuration update `
--attached-database-configuration-name azconfig  `
 --cluster-name "myfollower" `
 --resource-group "MY_RESOURCE_GROUP" `
--table-level tables-to-include=table1,table2,table3,table4,table5 `
--table-level materialized-views-to-include=*_view `
```

The result is that table1-table5 is not included. I also tried other syntax versions without success like

```
--table-level tables-to-include="table1","table2","table3","table4","table5" `
```

What is the correct syntax to specify an array of tables here ?

*Note:  New-AzKustoAttachedDatabaseConfiguration works with "table1", "table2", "table3" very well.*